# python import module time out

Tags: python, function, module

I am trying to build a function with netmiko (ssh session manager based on paramiko) and import it as a module. Here the function that I want import:

```
import sys, socket, getpass
from netmiko import ConnectHandler


def sshHost(hostname):
    username = raw_input("Username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass()
    hostIp = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    sshSession = ConnectHandler(device_type = 'juniper', ip = hostIp, username = username, password = password)
    versionHostname = sshSession.send_command("show version | match Hostname:")
    print "Session established with ",versionHostname.strip(), "IP: ", hostIp
    return sshSession
```

so, that function work as expected if I run `sshHost(sys.argv[1])`
however, when I import that as external module , the script times-out

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from sshHostModuleJUNOS import sshHost

def showVersion(host):
    out = host.send_command("show version")
    print out

showVersion(sshHost(sys.argv[1]))
```

I am quite sure something is wrong in the way I use the sshHost module but I cannot figure out what

error `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session`

Comment: are you sure its the import that is the problem? It sounds like your connection times out which is unrelated to importing

Comment: Not I am not sure. I assume as my sshHost function works properly by itself. Seems not working when I import into another script (so this is the base of my assumption)